# How can I make the code stop when input < 0 and when lowest tax is the same then it prints out the following countries

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

How can I make the code stop when the input<0 and when the lowest tax is the same. I have 4 countries and for example if Denmark and Norway have the same tax it will print out: "Denmark Norway" in alphabetical row. Here is an example:
Income: 1000000
Lowest tax: 150000.0
USA
Income: 6000
Lowest tax: 1500.0
Denmark Norway USA
Income: -1

Here is my code, it prints out the lowest value and it's country:

`

```
continue_input = True
income = 0

while continue_input and income >= 0:
    income = int(input('Income: '))

    # Canada   
    canada_tax = 0.26
    canada = canada_tax * income

    # Norway
    if income > 3000:
        norway_tax1 = 0.1 * 3000
        tax_left = income - 3000
        norway_tax2 = 0.4 * tax_left
        norway_tax = norway_tax1 + norway_tax2
    elif income < 3000:
        norway_tax = 0.1 * income

    # Denmark
    denmark_tax = 0
    percent = 0
    for _ in range(int(income/1000)):
      denmark_tax += percent * 1000
      percent += 0.1
      denmark_tax += percent * (income%1000)
      
    # USA
    if income <= 1500:
        USA_tax = 0.12 * income
    elif income > 1500 and income <= 6000:
        USA_tax = 0.25 * income
    elif income > 6000 and income <= 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.38 * income
    elif income > 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.15 * income



    #Print lowest tax
    if canada < norway_tax and canada < USA_tax and canada < denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {canada}')
        print('Canada')
    elif norway_tax < canada and norway_tax < USA_tax and norway_tax < denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {norway_tax}')
        print('Norway')
    elif USA_tax < canada and USA_tax < norway_tax and USA_tax < denmark_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {USA_tax}')
        print('USA')
    elif denmark_tax < canada and denmark_tax < norway_tax and denmark_tax < USA_tax:
        print(f'Lowest tax: {denmark_tax}')
        print('Denmark')
```

I'm expecting this:

Income: 1000000
Lowest tax: 150000.0
USA
Income: 6000
Lowest tax: 1500.0
Denmark Norway USA
Income: -1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [mre] and try to make a *minimal* example. Try removing parts of the functionality, until you isolate the *part which is causing a problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are taking the input inside the while loop, It will first execute all the calculations, then print and then check if income is less than 0 or not.

To avoid this you can remove `income>=0` condition from the while loop and instantly check if the value is negative or not. Also your code will not print if more than 1 country has minimum tax because you are only checking for less value and not equal.

A simple and easy way of solving both the above problem can be :-

```
continue_input = True
income = 0

# changed here
while continue_input :
    income = int(input('Income: '))

    # changed here
    if income < 0 :
        break

    # Canada   
    canada_tax = 0.26
    canada = canada_tax * income

    # Norway
    if income > 3000:
        norway_tax1 = 0.1 * 3000
        tax_left = income - 3000
        norway_tax2 = 0.4 * tax_left
        norway_tax = norway_tax1 + norway_tax2
    elif income < 3000:
        norway_tax = 0.1 * income

    # Denmark
    denmark_tax = 0
    percent = 0
    for _ in range(int(income/1000)):
      denmark_tax += percent * 1000
      percent += 0.1
      denmark_tax += percent * (income%1000)
      
    # USA
    if income <= 1500:
        USA_tax = 0.12 * income
    elif income > 1500 and income <= 6000:
        USA_tax = 0.25 * income
    elif income > 6000 and income <= 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.38 * income
    elif income > 10000:
        USA_tax = 0.15 * income
        

    # changed here
    min_tax = min(canada, norway_tax, USA_tax, denmark_tax)
    print(f'Lowest tax: {min_tax}', end = " ")

    if min_tax == canada :
        print('Canada', end = " ")

    if min_tax == denmark_tax :
        print('Denmark', end = " ")

    if min_tax == norway_tax :
        print('Norway', end = " ")

    if min_tax == USA_tax :
        print('USA',end= " ")
    print()
```

output :-

> ```
> Income: 1000000
> Lowest tax: 150000.0 USA 
> Income: 6000
> Lowest tax: 1500.0 Denmark Norway USA 
> Income: -1
> ```

PS:- I tweaked the print statements using `end = " "` so that you can get the output in desired form. I have also commented before I have made changes in the code

Comment: Thanks! Can I use something else than min()?

Comment: Other than min you can try and find the minimum value using if and else

Comment: Okay will do, and the break variable I haven't learned that yet, can I use something else than that? False for example?

Comment: enter the complete loop after input statement inside `if income>=0` and add back `income >= 0` condition in the `while` statement

Comment: Thanks! Can't I use the minimum value for the == values by using the if statement I used before? Or is that to complicated

Comment: The logic you used is wrong. It will not work if multiple countries have minimum value. For example, if income is 6000 that code will not print anything because more than 1 country has minimum value.  That might work if you use `<=` instead of just `<`. and change `elif` to `if`